# get NsMutableArray objecte in for loop

Tags: objective-c

I need to get array object in for loop in all the position ODD NUMBER I set the array with name. 
is this possible to set array name in for loop ?
now I get the name and not the array object.

```
NSMutableArray *array0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"name 1", nil]; 
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"name 2", nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"name 3", nil]; 
NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"name 4", nil];

NSMutableArray *nilObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", nil];

nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int countNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i<= 4 * 2; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        [nameArray addObject:nilObject];
        countNumber++;
    }
    else
    {
        [nameArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"array%i",i -countNumber]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create compound variable names at runtime.

A solution is to use a temporary array.

```
NSMutableArray *array0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name 1", nil];
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name 2", nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name 3", nil];
NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name 4", nil];

NSMutableArray *nilObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"", nil];
NSArray *tempArray = @[array0, array1, array2, array3];

NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int countNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i<= 4 * 2; i++)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
  {
    [nameArray addObject:nilObject];
    countNumber++;
  }
  else
  {
    [nameArray addObject:tempArray[countNumber - 1]];
  }
}
```